# PermissionError pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

pip install has suddenly stopped working - unsure if related to recent update. I've tried it both on pip 19.0.3 and pip.20.0.2
When using:

```
python -m pip install matplotlib --user
```

I get an error like this

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\accesstest_deleteme_fishfingers_custard_d1677h'
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: ```accesstest_deleteme_fishfingers_custard_d1677h``` this is... unexpected. Have you tried closing all active python sessions and deleting it manually?

Comment: Don't put the answer/solution in the Question. Mark the answer ([your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60621701/2745495)) as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Yes, need to wait 2 days for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to run your terminal as an administrator-elevated account to access the restricted resource.

Comment: I believe I am running it as admin already. I use windows+r, cmd, ctrl+shift+enter